# My windows doesn't render properly

Tags: linux-mint, gnome

I accidentally installed GNOME with these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After I rebooted my computer, some of the GUI parts like the outlines of buttons were gone:

[image]

I have tried to remove the PPA's and update, but that didn't work.

Comment: The commands you've listed wouldn't install GNOME. They would only add the repo. I assume you forgot one at the end?

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I am running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit, with GTK+ 3.20.8. I have tried different themes, and it's a problem on all of them

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly remove the PPAs and their packages you will need to use `ppa-purge` as it says in the notice from the PPAs when you added them. Install `ppa-purge` with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Firstly you must make sure that the PPAs are in your sources so if you removed them please run again:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run:

```
sudo ppa-purge gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge gnome3-team/gnome3
```

And restart your machine.

Comment: Now the window manager shuts down immediately after boot. I don't know if it was the commands you sent or something else I did beforehand. I will just reinstall the OS. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ViktorHundahlStrate: The commands I gave should have only returned your system to the state it was before you added those PPAs and installed stuff from them. The problems you have now are more likely to be caused by something else you did.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was something else I tried, to fix the problem. But thanks for the suggestion. I will remember the ppa-purge command :)

Comment: Well, if you could provide a list of the things you tried (if they were in Terminal then perhaps use the `history` command) then I could try and help you further. But if you would prefer to just reinstall then that's fine. :)